# Flickering with transparent panel

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, panel

I've created a simple program and now i'm in the stages of doing my designing. I've got a multiple Panels which i make visible / invisible to switch between "tabs" (EG. 1 panel for the login screen and 1 panel for the create account screen). Now i've made these panels invisible because i want them just as containers to be able to quickly move around controls and create buttons in.

My problem is that i've set my forms background image to a image i made in photoshop and whenever i switch between panels it flickers, whenever i just use a system color (white,black) this doesn't happen.
Is there any way for me to remove the flickering?

i've tried :

- Setting double buffer to true
- protected overrideing OnPaint, CreateBackground, and Createparam

my code is extremely basic :

```
private void btnNewAcc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PanelNewAccount.Visible = true;
        PanelLogin.Visible = false;
    }
```

Comment: Without seeing your code I can only advise to to try a double-buffered panel subclass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Patrick i've solved my problem,
instead of using panels i'm using a TabControl and i assigned the same background to each tab.
Just as easy to add dynamic buttons as well.
Same features as panels but without the flickering.

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer?

Answer (score 1):

Try to setting the form property DoubleBuffered to true, in winforms the flickering usually happens because the GDI+ is trying to draw the control(s) a lot of times so DoubleBuffering you graphics should help in such cases

```
form.DoubleBuffered = true;
```

Comment: Yea sorry, i was just editing my post, i've already tried that but no effect whatsoever i'm afraid

Comment: @BornToGrill have you tried using the TabControl?, I used the same approach in a test application and it did not flickered

Comment: I don't see how i could use it as a substitude, i haven't really used TabControls but i can't find how to make it transparent , i'm also not sure if it allows me to add buttons dynamically like i need to

Comment: @BornToGrill you just have to use the TabPage to add buttons dynamically, but I dont know a way to make it transparent, but you could set its background image instead of the forms

Comment: you sure are a genius. It's gonna take me a long time but i can change my code to work with TabControls! thank you so much

Comment: Double buffer did not work for me. However setting the form opacity to 0 initially and  then setting it back to 1 using a timer after about 100ms worked for me

Answer (score 0):

```
#region .. Double Buffered function ..
       public static void SetDoubleBuffered(System.Windows.Forms.Control c)
        {
            if (System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.TerminalServerSession)
                return;
            System.Reflection.PropertyInfo aProp = typeof(System.Windows.Forms.Control).GetProperty("DoubleBuffered", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
            aProp.SetValue(c, true, null);
        }

       #endregion


#region .. code for Flucuring ..

       protected override CreateParams CreateParams
        {
            get
            {
                CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
                cp.ExStyle |= 0x02000000;
                return cp;
            }
        }

        #endregion
```

Even though i am late but if somebody else is also suffering from the same problem then this code fixed the flickering for me even though i dont know how it works.
I found it [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/728551/Remove-flickering-due-to-TableLayoutPanel-Panel-in).
Add the above code snippet in your program and in the contructor of your app add this line:

```
SetDoubleBuffered(YourPanelName);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
protected override CreateParams CreateParams {
      get {
        CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
        cp.ExStyle |= 0x02000000;
        return cp;
      }
    }
```

code copy from [codeproject](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/112132/Flicker-free-Form-Painting) solved my problem.